# cant this question be solved other then the method involving integration and differentiation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

the question was :

A particle moves along the X-axis as

$$x=u(t-2s)+a(t-2 s)² .  $$

(a) the initial velocity of the particle is $u$

(b) the acceleration of the particle is $a$

(c) the acceleration of the particle is $2a$

(d) at $t=2$ s particle is at the origin.

This is how my teacher explained :
  the ans is  (c), (d)

Explanation:   The velocity at any instant is given by $$v=\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=u+2a(t-2) $$
initial velocity is the velocity at t=0, putting this value we get 
$$v=u-4a$$
which is not zero. So (a) is incorrect.

Acceleration is given by $$\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dr} =2a,$$
So (b) is incorrect and (c) is correct.

Putting t=2 s in the given displacement equation we get x=0, so (d) is also correct.

I totally understand the above method, but my question is that can't  we simply compare the equation
$$x=u(t-2s)+a(t-2 s)² $$  with $$s=ut+\frac{1}{2}a(t)²?$$

Using my method, I got ans as an option a, c, and d. But ans is just option c and d. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is the $s$ supposed to be ?

Comment: @StephenG   I suspect $2s$ is meant to be $2$ seconds.

Comment: It would help if your teacher would use a more standard functional form.  I would have formulated this equation as: $x=v_0(t-2)+ka(t-2)^2$.  Including "s" (an apparent unit) inside the parentheses while showing no units anywhere else is ambiguous.  Leaving off the "k" implies that $a=2a$, which is algebraically incorrect, or ambiguous by implying that "a" in the equation is a variable which is different than the standard physics nomenclature of "a" for acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part.  This is the equation of position as a function of time for uniformly accelerated motion with $t$ shifted by $t_0=2s$, *i.e.* in terms of $(t-t_0)$ rather than just $t$.

Note that the velocity at $t=t_0=2s$ is $u$ but that’s not the *initial* velocity.  Since the acceleration is constant with $t$, you can read it off at any $t$, including a $t=t_0=2s$, to be $2a$ as you found.

The time-shifted equation for the velocity will be (again by simply comparing with known solution)
$$
v(t)=u+2a (t-t_0)
$$
so that, at $t=0$, you get $v(0)=u - 2a t_0= u-4a$ as indicated.

Comment: I don't understand how velocity at t=2s is u? can u please elaborate this part.

Comment: If $x=x_0+u t + \frac{1}{2} A t^2 $ for $t_0=0$ with $v=u$ at $t=0$, then compare $x=u(t-t_0)+a(t-t_0)^2$ at $t=t_0$.

Comment: oh, thanks .. now I understand it.